# Using COUNT(*) versus an individual value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I seem to recall someone telling me a long time ago that using `COUNT(*)` in a MySQL statement to check if a row exists is the most efficient method (versus `COUNT(some_column_name)`), but I am not sure. Is this true? Should we be using `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(some_column_name)`?

Comment: see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's the same for MySQL?...

Comment: See the manual, it's explained there: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: All right... guess that settles it, although they are unclear on the InnoDB part. Thanks, Mr. horse.

Comment: The predicates in the query (e.g. conditions in the WHERE clause) and availability of suitable indexes will have a much larger impact on how efficient a search for an existing row is. (The big difference, in terms of the result returned, between the two options you show comes when `some_column_name` is nullable.) In terms of efficiency, it depends whether `some_column_name` is available in the index used by the query, avoiding a lookup of the underlying data page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(some_column)` counts the number of non-`null` values in that column. Essentially, you're forcing the database to read all the values for that column (regardless of whether its done via table access or some index).

`count(*)` counts the number of rows in the table, thus leaving the database a larger freedom of choice with regards to which indexes to use. Theoretically, this could be faster.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(*)` counts all rows in the result set (or group if using GROUP BY).
`COUNT(column_name)` only counts those rows where column_name is NOT NULL. This may be slower in some situations even if there are no NULL values because the value has to be checked (unless the column is not nullable).
`COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` since 1 can never be NULL.

To see the difference in the results you can try this little experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (x INT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES (1), (2), (NULL);
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS a,
    COUNT(x) AS b,
    COUNT(1) AS c FROM table1;
```

Result:

```
a   b   c 3   2   3
```